# Java Timer not working

Tags: java, timer

I have an `Image` named `worldImageToUse` and I have a `Timer` that is supposed to toggle `worldImageToUse` between two images every 1 second. But it does not seem to work. Help Please?

```
public void startWorldImageFlash() {
        worldImageFlashTimer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(worldImageToUse == worldImage) setWorldImageBW();
                if(worldImageToUse == worldImageBW) setWorldImageColor();
            }
        };
        worldImageFlashTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
    }


public void stopWorldImageFlash() {
        worldImageFlashTimer.cancel();
        setWorldImageColor();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked twice, change the second if with "else if", that will solve the problem. Also, you should consider debugging in such cases :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code says if color set to black and white.  Then says if black and white set to color.   Wouldn't you end up with the same image every time.  Your second if needs to be an else if.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `repaint()` the component afer setting the image?